# Vb Guessing Game Random generator broken

Tags: vb.net, random

In my code,I have now realised I have to use the New Random function, my code was working before with the Randomize and then the numbers but now it comes up with loads of errors and wont even let me run the program. I think it is only a small error but I just need some help to get the final bit going 
Heres the code and thanks for any help :)

I cannot get the code to work with the randomly generated number and I have to use the New Random function I cannot use randomize() Does anybody know how to help here is the code.

```
    Dim timestook As Int32 = 1
    Dim usersguess As Integer
    Dim value = New Random(0 - 19)
    Console.WriteLine("You have to guess this number. It is between 1 and 20. Good Luck !")

    usersguess = Console.ReadLine()
    'keep looping until they get the right value
    While usersguess <> value
        'now check how it compares to the random value
        If usersguess < value Then
            timestook = timestook + 1
            Console.WriteLine("You're too low. Go higher ")
        ElseIf usersguess > value Then
            Console.WriteLine("You're too high. Go Lower.")
            timestook = timestook + 1
        End If
        'If they are wrong the code will run again,after telling the user if they are too high or too low.
        usersguess = Console.ReadLine()

    End While
    '        Console.WriteLine("You're correct. Well Done")
    If usersguess = value Then
        Console.WriteLine("You took,{0}", timestook)
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: thats not how you use [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).  `New` creates an instance of the random class, not a random number

Comment: So how do I create a random number without using the Randomize function

Comment: 1.  Follow the link.  2. Read.  3. Profit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do some googling on [how to use random numbers](http://www.dotnetperls.com/random-vbnet). Your problem is that you aren't creating a `Random` object to handle the random number generation.

Here's how you can fix your code:

```
Dim randNumGen As New Random() 'Create Random object
Dim value As Integer = randNumGen.Next(0, 20) 'set value equal to a new random number between 0-19
```

Please note that this code could be further refactored for readability and simplicity (like changing `timestook = timestook + 1` to `timestook += 1` and selecting better variable names like `numberOfGuesses` as opposed to `timestook`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `New Random(0-19)` does not do at all what you think it does, name it does **NOT** return an integer. Instead, it creates an instance of a [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random(v=vs.110).aspx) object, which is a type that knows how to create new random values. The `0-19` part of the expression is the *seed* for the [Random object's constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx), and is the same as just passing the value `-19`.

This looks like it's either homework or personal practice, so I feel like you will be better served in this case with a separate example using the `Random` type for reference than you would if I fixed the code sample in the question for you:

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(0, 20))
Next i
```

It's also worth mentioning here that you typically only want *one* `Random` object for your entire program, or at least only one `Random` object for each logical part of your program. Creating new `Random` objects resets the seeds, and for best results you want to follow the same seed on subsequent calls to the same instance for a while.